# Node.js incorrect path problems

Tags: node.js

When I do `fs.readFile(file...` I get this error:

> { [Error: ENOENT, open 'foundation/css/normalize.css']
>
> errno: 34,
>
> code: 'ENOENT',
>
> path: 'foundation/css/normalize.css' }

Do I have to route my path in relation to the HTML file they are linked from, or in relation to the location of the node.js files running the server and router?

And no, I'm not using express and "use express" is not an acceptable answer.

---

Edit

@BenjaminGruenbaum's last comment. I'm not sure what you mean by my HTTP response, but my code logic is as follows: I load my index.html via the URI and when it `readFile` the document it then recursively goes through every other linked file. I have a script that breaks it down to properly display the right `Content-Type`. I'll include it here because its too long for a comment:

```
function route(handle, pathname, response, request){
// console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);

if (typeof handle[pathname] === "function"){        
    handle[pathname](response, request);
    } else {

    // console.log('NON HTML');
    // console.log(pathname);

    var file_path = "";
    var mimes = {
        'css':  'text/css',
        'js':   'text/javascript',
        'htm':  'text/html',
        'html': 'text/html',
        'png': 'image/png',
        'jpg': 'image/jpg',
        'jpeg': 'image/jpeg'
    };

    // parses the url request for a file and pulls the pathname
    var url_request = url.parse(request.url).pathname;      
    // console.log('URL REQUEST');
    // console.log(url_request);

    // finds the placement of '.' to determine the extension    
    var tmp  = url_request.lastIndexOf(".");
    // determines the extension by uing .substring that takes everything after '.'
    var extension  = url_request.substring((tmp + 1));
    // console.log('EXTENSION');
    // console.log(extension);


    //set path of static pages
    if (extension === 'css' || extension === 'js' || extension === 'htm' || extension === 'html' || extension === 'png' || extension === 'jpg' || extension === 'jpeg'){

        // console.log('LOAD STATIC PAGE');
        file_path = url_request.replace("/", "");
        // console.log(file_path);
        // console.log();
    }

    //load needed pages and static files
    fs.readFile(file_path, function (error, data){
        if(error){
            // console.log("AM I DEAD");

            // console.log(error);
            // console.log();
            response.writeHeader(500, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
            response.write("<h1>FS READ FILE ERROR: Internal Server Error!</h1>");    
        }
        else{
            response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": mimes[extension]});  

            console.log('SHOULD BE SUCCESS')
            console.log(mimes[extension]);
            // console.log(data);
            response.write(data);
        }

        response.end();  
    });
    response.end();
}
}

exports.route = route;
```

As you can tell by how many places I have `console.log()` I can track it all the way to the bottom It fails here:

```
else{
            response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": mimes[extension]});  

            console.log('SHOULD BE SUCCESS')
            console.log(mimes[extension]);
            // console.log(data);
            response.write(data);
        }
```

I apologize for the somewhat sloppy indentation.

---

Final edit:

The eventual resolution to this stupid situation can be found at my following question here: [Node.js - Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006730/node-js-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-pla/18007091?noredirect=1#18007091)

Much thanks to @BenjaminGruenbaum for putting up with a Noob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use the path relative to your NodeJS files (the entry point more specifically) and not your client-side HTML.

This is just like it works in bash scripts, in Python and pretty much in any other language with a sane API that makes sane calls to the native file system functions in the operating system.

In fact, the client side HTML has little to do with pathing in Node - in Node's stand point it's just text being sent in an HTTP response to the client. It's not aware of the server's inner file system at all.

(Also, I don't see how anything like express would even be any help anyway)

Comment: Thanks. Give me 5 min and I'll give it a try. I just threw that in about express because that tends to be the most regular response to any node question. It bugs the hell out of me

Comment: I gave it a whirl and it didnt work. I'm not sure how to convey this with text, but my file structure is as follows: `main_folder/assets/foundation + images + JS`  my node files are in the JS folder. So I have the path to my foundation files as `../foundation/css/normalize.css` but It still doesnt work

Comment: Let's isolate this. Create a new file called server.js , in the same directory create a file called `README` and writing "Hello World" in it. All server.js does is call fs.readFile on README. Now play with pathing, do `../dirname/README` - that still works. Now try putting README in a new directory and see pathing still works. (I just verified all this in my box by the way). Now that you are convinced that the problem is not woth pathing try debugging it - print console logs on the path and open it manually in terminal, spelling errors happened to me tens of times :)

Comment: While I work on isolating this, I think that _maybe_ it is pathing right but something is happening with my `Content-Type` association. In my inspector I get this error:
`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost:8000/foundation/css/normalize.css".`

Comment: Just to be clear, the path should be relative to where the script is executed from, not necessarily where the script is located on the filesystem.

Comment: @JDillon522 Again, NodeJS does not care about what it sends to the browser. The content type (set it to the correct value by adding the header btw :)) means we got to the client side and the problem is not an ENOENT anymore. However if you get that message it means you're _past_ your original problem :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum First off: Thanks for helping me out. Thats epic. 
Second: I managed to get all the ENOENT errors to go away and I resolved all path issues. I still get the previous error where it interprets the styesheet but transferred it wrong with the wrong type. I've managed to confirm via `console.log`ing everything and I am able to get the proper Header `Content-Type` to where it `response.write(data)` from the `fs.readFile`. However, I cant figure out how it drops the ball between there and writing it.

Comment: @JDillon522 Where are you adding the mime type to the header? It should be on your HTTP response just to be clear.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum please see the edit above for an expanded reply